# three.js get Object3D by custom property

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm creating `LineSegments` objects like this:

```
const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
geometry.setAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(vertices, 3));

const edges = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(geometry);
const line = new THREE.LineSegments(edges2, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffffff }));
scene.add(line);
```

Then I've added custom properties to my lines:

```
line.prop1 = "hello";
line.prop2 = "world";
```

How can I get all Objects where `prop1` for example is `"hello"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a built-in method for this use case. [Object3D.getObjectByProperty()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=obje#api/en/core/Object3D.getObjectByProperty) only works if an object has a unique property value. This function should do the trick:

```js
function getObjectsByProperty( object, property, value, result = [] ) {

    // check the current object

    if ( object[ property ] === value ) result.push( object );
  
    // check children

    for ( let i = 0, l = object.children.length; i < l; i ++ ) {

        const child = object.children[ i ];

        getObjectsByProperty( child, property, value, result );

    }
   
  return result;

}

//

const objects = getObjectsByProperty( scene, 'prop1', 'hello' );
```